# how to reload page after handle state?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, react-bootstrap

My sidebar in the responsive mode not working correctly, i'm use @media for controller width of page, when is responsive i use position:absolute for sidebar button stay in up of content, i created a state for onclick is active change this position:relative but is not working, help please. The page in the mode normal funciton correctly, and mode responsive (Ctrl + shift + I) too but i click in the button the problemn happens.

**Sidebar.js**

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classStyle: "sidebar"
    };
  }

  // handleSidebar(value) {
  //  this.setState = ({ classStyle : value });
  // }

   handleSidebar = (value) => { 
    this.setState = ({ classStyle: value }); 
  }


render() {
  return (
    
    <div className={this.state.classStyle}>
      <Navbar bg="light" variant="light" sticky="top" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" onClick={() => handleSidebar("sidebarR")} />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

**Index.css**

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
{
    .sidebar
    {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .sidebarR 
    {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: is class "sidebarR" applied to div after click ?

Comment: @YatinMistry not is.

Comment: change handleSidebar to arrow function handleSidebar = (value)  => {
    this.setState = ({ classStyle : value });
  } and  click event as onClick={() => handleSidebar("sidebarR")}

Comment: @YatinMistry without "this" in onClick is return handleSidebar is not defined and when i add "this" in on click nothing happens.

Comment: @YatinMistry I edited my code for suggest that you indicated .

Comment: this must be required. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one, it is working

Replace this function in your component

```
 handleSidebar = () => { 
     console.log("clicked");
     this.setState({ classStyle: "sidebarR" }); 
   }
```

If you want toggle class then use below function,

```
 handleSidebar = () => { 
     console.log("clicked");
     const classStyle = this.state.classStyle == "sidebar" ? "sidebarR" : "sidebar";
     this.setState({ classStyle: classStyle }); 
   }
```

Running Component without Navbar Component,

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './Menu.css';


export default class Menu extends Component {
 
  
    state = {
       classStyle: "sidebar"
     };
   
 
    handleSidebar = () => { 
     console.log("clicked");
     this.setState({ classStyle: "sidebarR" }); 
   }
 
 
 render() {
   return (
     
     <div className={this.state.classStyle}>
       
         <p onClick={() => this.handleSidebar()} >Menu</p>
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `handleSidebar` on `onClick`, you need to use `this`

```js
Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" onClick={() => this.handleSidebar("sidebarR")} />
```

Comment: i put but nothing happens after.